# How to get the cell tower area using the CellID and LAC in Android?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, cellid

I am able to get the Cell Id and LAC(Local Area Code). But don't know how to decode the location. I should not connect to internet and should get the cell tower location using Cell Id and LAC.

If remember the basic model phones(Not built on Android) have an option to get that. 
The option is something like "Cell Info Display". If we enable it it used to show the current area on Phone main screen.

Is there any way to get the local area where the phone connected to on Android?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial about this on AndDev.org:

[Poor mans GPS - Cell(Tower)ID / Location Area Code -Lookup](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android's [Network provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) does this for you.

If you are using any Android phone you have this facility of getting your location from your Cell ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can you this android app to convert gsm location into gps coordinates [GPS Convertor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mab.gpsconv).
Enter gsm coordinates as follow:

1. cellid
2. ';'
3. loc_area_code

e.g: 123;456

Click 'Start Conversion' button to return GPS coordinates